# Group Item click in Expandablelist view?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a imageView on expandable listview's group view. I want to get the group position when I click on this imageView. In bindGroupView method I can set OnClickListener.  But problem is this method will not return me group position. I have written code for OnGroupClickListener. But this call's when i click on group view anywhere except this imageview. How to implements it?

Comment: kindly provide your code here for better review and to get proper solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your group view using the following method

```
getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

When you pass view back to android, attach the position of the group (groupPosition) to the image view using the method `imageView.setTag()`. You can retrieve the position back on the onClickListener of the imageView. The view is passed to the onClick method when it is called.

```
onClick(View v)
```